# Passing String through Segue

Tags: ios, nsstring, segue

I'm trying to pass a NSMutableString through a segue.
The mutableString is a title from an MKPolygon.
I've done the mutableString like this: `self.titleString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:polygon.title];`

I'm not sure how to segue the String:
I've got this now:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"PickerViewController"])
    {
        NSLog(@"delegated");

        //Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        PickerViewController *vc =[segue destinationViewController];
        vc.titleString = titleString;
    }
}
```

I get an error with `vc.titleString = titleString;`. Not sure how to set the String in the PickerViewController segue.
Error: `Property 'titleString' not found on object of type 'PickerViewController *'`

The PerformSegueWithIdentifier is this Method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    //this would be the yes button or cancel
    if (buttonIndex == 0 ){

        NSLog(@"ButtonIndex Okay");
    }
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PickerViewController" sender:self];
    }
}
```

I do know how to segue an object, but with Strings I don't get my mind to it.
Help would be really appreciated!

---

**Update 1:**

- I've imported the `PickerViewController.h` in the `ViewController.h` file.
- I've changed the `vc.titleString = titleString;` with `vc.titleString = self.titleString;`
- I've added a `@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableString *titleString;` to the `PickerViewController.h`

No luck.

---

**Update 2:**

- Tried an other way to segue the String: `[(PickerViewController *)[segue destinationViewController] setTitleString:self.titleString];`

Got the error: `No visible @interface for 'PickerViewController' declares the selector 'setTitleString:'`

ViewController.h file:

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableString *titleString;`

ViewController.m file:

`@synthesize titleString;`
`self.titleString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];`

PickerViewController.h file:

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableString *titleString;`

PickerViewController.m file:

`@synthesize titleString;`
`self.titleString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];`

Still seems like it doesn't recognises the `titleString`.

---

**Update 3:**

Still no luck with segueing the string.

Maybe it has something to with this:

The NSMutableString is being used in a loop. The loop checks if there is an GPS, annotation or a touch is inside a MKPolygon. Each polygon has it's own color, which is named in the polygon.title: See code below*. So the String saves the 'selected' polygon title. See the loop below:

One of the Polygons:

```
    CLLocationCoordinate2D roodPoly[2];
    roodPoly[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.372445351278294, 4.876454472541809);
    roodPoly[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.37288748990477, 4.878369569778442);

    MKPolygon *roodpoly = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:roodPoly count:2];
    roodpoly.title = @"red";
    [myMapView addOverlay:roodpoly];
```

A little bit of the loop:

```
            if(CGPathContainsPoint(mpr , NULL, mapPointAsCGP, FALSE)){

                NSLog(@"Coordinate %f,%f is in polygon %@", tapCoord.latitude, tapCoord.longitude, polygon.title);

                self.titleString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:polygon.title];
                self.subtitleString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:polygon.subtitle];

                alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Found it" message:subtitleString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Stel notificatie in", nil];
                [alertView show];

                NSLog(@"The color of the Polygram is: %@", titleString);

            }

            CGPathRelease(mpr);
        }
    }
}
```

I thought this could cause the problem for not finding the String :(

Comment: You are doing it right - simply make sure that (1) `PickerViewController` defines a property `titleString`, and (2) that `PickerViewController.h` is included in the .m file where you are processing the segue.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Try `vc.titleString = self.titleString;`.

Comment: Could you put the error you are getting ?

Comment: @rdelmar I get the error: `Property 'titleString' not found on object of type 'PickerViewController *` 
@dasblinkenlight I've already defined the property `titleString` in the `ViewController.h`, also include the `PickerViewController.h` in the .m file.
@GlennRay I've tried that but no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your "PickerViewController.h" should look like:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PickerViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableString * titleString;

@end
```

And on your "ViewController.m" file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "PickerViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    [(PickerViewController *) [segue destinationViewController] setTitleString:self.titleString];
}
@end
```

It is Working fine here..

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Still no luck. See update, Maby it has something to do with the (nonatomic, strong) or something? Should be readwrite?

Comment: had you tried to `[(PickerViewController *)[segue destinationViewController] setTitleString:self.titleString];` ?

Comment: No I didn't. For what do I have to replace it?

Comment: Doesn't understand the settitleString: `No visible @interface for 'PickerViewController' declares the selector 'setTitleString:'`

Comment: Seems like it still doesn't understand the NSString Property...
I've defined and synthesized it in all the necessary .h and .m files :(

Comment: Yes, your update works in a new project. But in application project it still doesn't recognise the titeString.. :(

Comment: @DaxRahusen pass me a zip with your project on my mail